# Extract Numbers from a String Column that contains certain substrings

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to Extract Numbers in another Column from a column Work_Experience

```
**Work_Experience**  
3 Month  
7 month  
11 Months  
8 months  
0
```

and I am looking for following output:

```
**Work_Experience**  ||   **Output**  
3 Month                   3  
7 month                   7  
11 Months                 11  
8 months                  8  
0                         0
```

This is what I tried

```
Experian_P2['Output'] = Experian_P2['Work_Experience'].str.contains('|'.join(['month', 'Month','months','Months'])).str.extract("(\d{1,2})")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
df['Output'] = df['Work_Experience'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*month').fillna(0)
```

*Pattern details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive match
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `month` - a `month` string.

Answer (score 0):

if you know that first part will always be a number you can try this simple snippet

```py
a = ['3 Month', '7 month', '11 Months', '8 months', '0']

for x in a:
    parts = x.split(' ')

    print (x, int(parts[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) here.

You command doesn't really make sense as you are piping one command to generate a boolean Series, and then are trying to extract text from it:

```
Experian_P2['Work_Experience'].str.contains('|'.join(['month', 'Month','months','Months'])).str.extract("(\d{1,2})"
```

I think you want to **slice** and `extract` on this subset:

```
m = Experian_P2['Work_Experience'].str.contains('months?', case=False)

Experian_P2.loc[m, 'Output'] = Experian_P2.loc[m, 'Work_Experience'].str.extract("(\d{1,2})", expand=False)
```